# Where can I find pints of beer?

Tags: mad-bullets

I've been playing [Mad bullets](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.istomgames.madbullets&hl=en) for Android. A couple of missions that pop up are

> Shoot X pints of beer

as you can see in the image below. Does anyone know where I can find pints of beer?

[image: Shoot pints]

Comment: According to http://toucharcade.com/2014/07/29/mad-bullets-review/, 'with some interesting challenges like shooting the beers out of an innocent's hands without shooting the person by accident'. If this solves your problem, let me know and I can post it as an answer. I have not played the game myself so I'm unsure if that is enough to find the pints of beer.

Comment: Oh I see it now... it is a guy with a big moustache that pops up holding two pints of beer and you have to try to shoot the pints without hitting him. Cool, thanks! I still don't know if there is any action that triggers his appearance or if it is just random... I'll try to get a screenshot for your answer ;-)

Comment: It's alright, I've found a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [TouchArcade](http://toucharcade.com/2014/07/29/mad-bullets-review):

> ..with some interesting challenges like shooting the beers out of an innocent's hands without shooting the person by accident..

I have found a screenshot showing what the man holding the pints of beer looks like. He will have a green outline/glow around him as he is innocent, while the pints of beer will have a red outline/glow around them. He'll randomly appear throughout the game, and you must shoot the pints of beer out of his hands without shooting him.

[image]